# $_product->isSaleable() shows different value in list page and view page magento 2

Tags: product, addtocart, magento2.3.0

Issue: Out of stock set at admin side. On product list page display "Out of stock" while detail page shows "Add to cart" button.

I have print the $_product->isSaleable() function on list.phtml as well addtocart.phtml.
For the same product list.phtml displays NULL, while addtocart.phtml displays 1 on the view page(Product detail).
I have enabled the backorder for all product.

> http://staging.mpex.com/photography.html
>
> http://staging.mpex.com/panasonic-dmw-bgs1-battery-grip.html

Check the above product in list page shows "Out of stock" while detail page has "Add to Cart" Button. Also, this product doesn't include in any bundle product.