# How can we migrate the data and settings from one magento 2.3.0 to another 2.3.0

Tags: magento2.3.0, data-migration, data-migration-tool

There is some functionality issue with my site. And, I want to be sure that Is this issue in default Luma or not?

I want to migrate admin data on fresh **Magento2.3.0**

Answer (score 0):

If you've got access to the command line use mysqldump:

To dump the database (`-h [hostname]` is optional)

`mysqldump -u [username] –p[password] -h [hostname] [database_name] > [dump_file.sql]`

To restore the database (the reverse):

`mysqldump –u[user name] -p[password] -h [hostname] [database name] < [dump_file.sql]`

One thing you need to watch for is that 2.3 includes a statement to create a view

[Magento 2.3 introduced a view table which causes issue with import of mysql dump. What's it for?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/274777/70343)

Comment: Your solution will help to clone the site. But I need to check fresh vanilla migration.

Comment: Please check this Question. I am looking for this question's solution
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/278217/product-issaleable-shows-different-value-in-list-page-and-view-page-magento

Comment: In that case there isn't going to be an easy solution.  Once the site has been cloned maybe you can pick and choose what data you want by truncating tables.  If you truncate enough (including `setup_module`) you may be able to trigger a reinstall using setup:upgrade.  Probably going to be easier to just start with a fresh site and just apply your change on luma theme.